# How to write output of a spark dataframe to a log file as a structured output in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have created a spark dataframe in pyspark and I want to write the filtered output data to be written to a log file or text file.
Let's consider the below as df

```
df=spark.sql(select * from tbl1)
```

I want the below command's output in a text file or a log file

```
df.select("col1").show(5)
```

I tried the below but it's not working

```
with open("output.txt","a") as f:
     f.write(tabulate(df.select("col1").show(5),tablefmt="pretty"))
```

Expected output in the text file as in the image.

Is it possible to write the output to a text file with the tabulated structure? 
[image][image]

Comment: A followup question, why would you want to store that in a format that would make it un-readable by any program ?

Comment: Just curious how to use tabulate module in spark dataframe in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.select("col1").limit(5).collect()`. This will give you Array (or List of Row object in Python) and then you can write it in the format you want. I have not used tabulate so I do not have idea on how to use it. However, caution that in production, such options are never used.